# How to convert the byte class object into a string object

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, arduino-uno

```
import serial
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

data = serial.Serial('com3',115200)
while True:
    while (data.inWaiting() == 0):
    pass
ardstr = data.readline()
print (ardstr)
```

Here I am trying to get data from arduino but it is coming in the format `b'29.20\r\n'`. I want to have the data in the format `"29.20"` so I can plot it.

I tried `ardstr = str(ardstr).strip('\r\n')` and `ardstr.decode('UTF-8')` 
but none of them is working. My python version is 3.4.3.

What can I do to get the result as `"29.40"` rather than `"b'29.20\r\n'"`?

Comment: And `ardstr = data.readline().decode('utf8').rstrip()` would not give you the result you've wanted? (or do that on printing depending on your other plans with the value are).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried `ardstr = str(ardstr).strip('\r\n')` and `ardstr.decode('UTF-8')`

You were close!  As with the `.strip()` call, using the `.decode()` method *returns* the new value.

```
ardstr = ardstr.strip()
ardstr = ardstr.decode('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in a single line, you can try:

`ardstr = ardstr.decode('UTF-8').rstrip()`

`rstrip()` will return a copy of the string with the trailling characters removed.